# Accessing values of JS Global variables in HTML with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs

So I have a piece of HTML that looks something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      var foo = {
        bar: []
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I am trying to use PhantomJS to extract the value of foo.bar. How would I do this? So far I know I would have is structured like this:

```
var webPage = require('webpage'); 
var page = webPage.create();
page.open(MY_URL, function(status) {
  var foo = page.evaluate(function(){
    //gets javascript from the HTML in the response
    // and extracts foo from there
  });
});

console.log(someVar);
phantom.exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you should just be able to use

```
var foo = page.evaluate(function() {
  return window.foo
})
console.log('foo =', foo)
```

Comment: I should be able to.  However, there is one problem.  Although I can run `window.foo`, I can't access the `foo.bar` array even though `bar` comes up when I type `console.log(Object.keys(foo));`.

Comment: @TheLegendOfCode In that case, it seems your example above is a poor one

Comment: I changed `return window.foo` to `return JSON.stringify(window.foo)` and it says that `foo.bar` is completely empty.  However, when I threw the URL into google and printed foo.bar in the console, it was full.

Comment: @TheLegendOfCode obviously something is populating the `foo.bar` array after the page initially loads. Like I said, your example does not represent reality

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would, open url from phantom virtual browser and get a javascript returned value from webpage with phantom

```
const phantom = require('phantom');


openUrl = (req, res, next) => {
    let url = 'your url goes here';
    const {content, returnedFromPage} = await loadJsSite(url);
    return res.json(returnedFromPage);
}

loadJsSite = async (url) => {
  return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {

    const instance = await phantom.create();
    const page = await instance.createPage();
    await page.on('onResourceRequested', function(requestData) {
      console.info('Requesting', requestData.url);
    });

    const status = await page.open(url);
    var returnedFromPage = await page.evaluate(function() {
            return document.title;
        });
    const content = await page.property('content');

    await instance.exit();

    return resolve({content: content, returnedFromPage: returnedFromPage});

  })
}
```